# React JS Проблема с изменениями стилей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, localstorage, style

Всем привет, при вызове функции `checktime()`  вылазит ошибка: ругается на `style`
Если закомментить все строки где есть `style` то всё прекрасно запускается. Может есть какая-нибудь альтернатива?

```js
export default function ProfileCard({ user, loading, className, verifyEmail, emailVerifying }) {

    function checkTime (){
        var date = new Date();
        var trueTime = date.getTime();
        if (localStorage.getItem("timeToUnblock") && trueTime > localStorage.getItem("timeToUnblock")) {
            document.getElementById("RegisterButton").style.visibility = "visible";
            localStorage.removeItem("timeToUnblock");
        } else if (!localStorage.getItem("timeToUnblock")) {
            document.getElementById("RegisterButton").style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("RegisterButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };

    function  VerifEmailButton() {
        var date = new Date();
        var trueTime = date.getTime();
        var timeToUnblock = date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + 10000); //900000
        localStorage.setItem("timeToUnblock", timeToUnblock);
        document.getElementById("RegisterButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
        verifyEmail();
    };
  return ( 
  {checkTime()}
          {!user.isEmailVerified &&
            !user.verificationEmailWasSent && (
              <Button
                type="success"
                size="md"
                onClick={VerifEmailButton()}
                disable={emailVerifying}
                className={classes.verifyButton}
                id={'RegisterButton'}
              >
                Верифицировать почту
              </Button>
            )}
            );
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, выкладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да это ж не  jquery, какой ещё getElementById, да и элемента то в ДОМе ещё нет, когда функция запускается. Чтобы сделать по нормальному можете добавить проп isVerified, в зависимости от него или рендерите кнопку или нет:

```
{props.isVerified && (<Button onClick={props.onVerify} ... />)
```

Потом в родительском компоненте..:

```
render() {
 return (
   <ProfileCard isVerified={...} onVerify={...} />
 )
}
```

Значения isVerified и функция передаваемая в коллбек будут или сидеть в родительском компоненте, или где-то в сторе вашего приложения, если такой есть.

Comment: Спасибо большое!